# Manual refresh loads older version site

Tags: php, android, html, .htaccess

So I am making a small web app using php. I'm just inserting into a MYSQL hosted at eHost. http://www.gearedwebdesigns.com/BPHCalcEnter.php

I have zero problems on desktop with caching. Different story on my android Galaxy s7 in Chrome. If I use the chrome inspector and remote devices then I can see the latest php update by doing CTRL+Shift+F5. However, if I refresh by pulling down then it loads an older version. I have tried clearing cache multiple times.

I've added this to my .htaccess

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|php|css)$">
FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
  Header set Pragma "no-cache"
  Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>
```

And I have this at the top of my php file.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: aggressive chrome caching is already an anecdote :-)
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=136320
He even caches DELITE requests :-)

Comment: It seems to happen on Firefox as well on my Android. It looks like it's loading the same old php page.

Comment: disable browser caching in the debugger and check

Comment: Are you talking about under Remote Devices? I've done that and it does display the latest version but still when I swipe down on my Android to activate a refresh, it loads the old page. Only in Chrome, though. I haven't set up Firefox for mobile debugging.